# Sharepoint Online Search - PnP-Js-Core

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, sharepoint-search, pnp-js-core

I'm doing a SharePoint search and I need specifically select Title field, but, some times the result is the title of the document and not the Title field of the library or list

I'm using PnP-Js-Core

My code

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let listName = encodeURIComponent(this.listName);
  let query: string = `contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True path:${this.siteUrl}/${listName}/ ${text}`;
  pnp.sp.search(<SearchQuery>{
    Querytext: query,
    SelectProperties: ['Title'],
  })
    .then((r: SearchResults) => {
      resolve(r.PrimarySearchResults);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      reject(null);
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Title managed property is mapped, by default, to more than just the Title column in SharePoint and SharePoint Online. So, in your query for "Title", in addition to ows_Title, you are also getting values from Basic:displaytitle, TermTitle, MetadataExtractorTitle, and Title. If you want only your List or Library Item Title field you may want to configure your own queryable Managed Property and map it to ows_Title.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I already got the title field of the list, but it is only shown for some documents, for example for pdf and images, the title is not shown

greetings and thanks

Comment: In the document library, you have to expressly set the Title field it is not the same as the Filename field. Ensure that the property value correctly.